# Can ZXing.Net be used in a Universal Windows app?

Tags: c#, windows, win-universal-app, zxing, windows-10-universal

I am having issues creating the app I am desiring. Currently, I am wanting to create a simple Universal Windows app that can utilize ZXing.Net to scan barcodes from a windows 10 tablet.

I am very new to creating Universal Windows apps and am lost on how to get it to work. I think one of my issues is that I am on a windows 8.1 machine and cannot debug since it is a windows 10 app.

My question boils down to: How can I use zxing.net in a Windows 10 Universal Windows app for use on a Windows 10 Tablet? If not, is there a way to create a windows 8 Universal Windows app that can be used on a Windows 10 tablet?

Thanks for any suggestions or tips.

EDIT - I am currently working on Visual Studios 2015

Comment: just add the nuget package to the mobile version and use the controls, it's very easy: https://www.nuget.org/packages/ZXing.Net.Mobile/

Comment: mobile version? I have added the nuget package to my [Blank App (Universal Windows)] project and I am unsure on where to go from here. Will I need a seperate project? Sorry if I seem very stupid, first time working with Universal Windows and anything app related in Visual Studios.

Comment: No prob :), you must add the .mobile version of zxing.net, it's an specific version for Android, iOS (using Xamarin), Windows Phone and WIndows Universal. First of all remove the standar version of the nuget package, add the mobile one and then use the examples on the zxing github to have a guide on how to implement it: https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile/tree/master/Samples

Comment: Alright, I did as you said and now I am trying to see how the sample works, but when trying to open the Universal Windows sample It tells me that the project type is not supported in my VS2015. I tried working around this and just throwing the files into a Universal Windows app I just created. The only issue (from errors) is that the namespace Microsoft.ApplicationInsights cannot be found.

Comment: You can safely remove all the application insights related code, it's for application analysis and you don't need it :)

Comment: Alright, looks a lot better now. Thank you for all the help! Now to figure out how to test it on a windows 7 machine

Comment: Basically... you can't... you need at least WIndows 10 to test it.

Comment: Well drats, guess I will need to figure out a way around that. Would I be able to remote into a virtual machine running windows 10 and test it that way?